# Adding data to a Hashmap using "put"

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to add elements to a hashmap using "put". But the program does not want to compile. Am getting error message "cannot find symbol - variable phoneBook". The error occurs at line "*phoneBook.put(name, number);*".

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MapTester {

     public void main(String args[]){

        HashMap<String, String> phoneBook = new HashMap<String, String>();
        phoneBook.put("Jenna Simpson", "3424 6785");       
     }

     public void enterNumber (String name, String number)
     {
         phoneBook.put(name, number);
     }
}
```

Comment: Your phonebook hashmap is declared inside your main, declare it above your main under your class definition

Comment: is phoneBook an instance varibale in your class?

Comment: Thanks, will try that and get back to you.

Comment: Please read about scope of variables in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified it to the below; it complies now. Thank you guys!

```
import java.util.HashMap;


    public class MapTester{

        HashMap<String, String> phoneBook = new HashMap<String, String>();

        public void main(String args[])
        {

            phoneBook.put("Jenna Simpson", "3424 6785");

         }


        public void enterNumber (String name, String number)
        {
            phoneBook.put(name, number);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

phoneBook is out of reach in enterNumber. It has no visibility. Pass it as a parameter.

```
public void enterNumber (Map<String, String> phoneBook, String name, String number)
{
    phoneBook.put(name, number);
}
```

Comment: Can you help me out on this one please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824858/hashmap-key-to-value-associations/

Answer (score 0):

You must declare phoneBook object above your main and under the class definition or pass phoneBook as parameter to enterNumber function:

```
 public void enterNumber (HashMap<String, String> phoneBook, String name, String number) {
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the method `enterNumber` doesn't have access to the variable phoneBook.

You must declare it as an instance variable like this

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MapTester{

 HashMap<String, String> phoneBook = new HashMap<String, String>();

 public void main(String args[]){
    MapTester tester = new MapTester();
    tester.enterNumber("Jenna Simpson", "3424 6785");
 }

 public void enterNumber (String name, String number)
 {
     phoneBook.put(name, number);
 }
}
```

Also you have to create an object of the class Maptester. Because you cannot call the method `enterNumber` from the main method directly unless and otherwise the method is static. And if the method is declared static, then the map should also be a static variable.

Comment: Can you help me out on this one please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824858/hashmap-key-to-value-associations/

Answer (score 0):

Take some times to go through this tutorial on variable scope in java. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

```
public class MapTester {
private Map<String, String> phoneBook = new HashMap<String, String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MapTester tester = new MapTester();
    tester.enterNumber("Jenna Simpson", "3424 6785");       

}

public  void enterNumber (String name, String number)
{
    phoneBook.put(name, number);
}
```

}