# Key to Value associations

Tags: java

**What I am trying to do** is create cars, assign a name to each car created.

**Below is what I have done:**

```
//.....codes

 public class Cars {

        Map<String, Vehicle> vehicleNames = new HashMap <String, Vehicle>();
        Car car = new Car();
        private void execute(String[] instructions)
        {

           boolean blnExists =vehicleNames.containsKey(instructions[1]);
           System.out.println("Exists? : " + blnExists); 

             if (blnExists){
               if (instructions[1].equals("build")){
                   car.makeVisible();
                  }
              }
              else {
                  System.out.println("Does not exist yet!");
              }

//more codes.......
```

**The problem I am facing:**

The program compiles and works fine, car names are being stored in the HashMap as I wanted. But the cars created don't seem to be associated to their respective names.

Answer (score 2):

- First, you want to distinguish between a command to create a new car (`car name`) and a command to perform an action on an existing car (`carname action`).
- If it's a `car name` command, try to fetch the car from the map. If it's not found, create the car and add to map.
- If it's a `carname action` command, try to fetch the car from the map. If it's not found, display an error message. If it's found, perform the action on it.

Here's a suggested way to make your logic work :

```
if (instructions[0].equals("car")) {
    Vehicle v = vehicleNames.get(instructions[1]);
    if (v == null) {
        // put here the code that adds a vehicle to the map
    } else {
        // display a message that the vehicle already exists
    }
} else {
    Vehicle v = vehicleNames.get(instructions[0]);
    if (v == null) {
        // display a message that car was not found
    } else {
        // perform an action on existing car. For example :
        if (instructions[1].equals("build") {
            v.makeVisible();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @EagleTwo I assumed `makeVisible` is a method of your `Vehicle` class, but I never saw your `Vehicle` class, so perhaps I was wrong. Which class does `makeVisible` belong to?

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that the name of the car is the second instruction:

```
       boolean blnExists =carNames.containsKey(instructions[1]);
```

but that is correct only for a 'car' command.  For the other commands, the name of the car is the *first* instruction.

You also have an issue here:

```
           if (instructions[1].equals("build")){
               car.makeVisible();
              }
```

Variable `car` does not reference the car with the given name (you only checked its existence -- you didn't actually retrieve it yet), so the output will not correspond to that car.

There are some other strange things about your code, but nothing that I recognize as erroneous on a quick read-through.

Comment: You retrieve the car via the `Map`'s `get()` method.  You already do this elsewhere (later) in your code.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that `for` loop.  Personally, I would not bother with the `key` and `tab` variables (for a single use each I'd just use `entry.getKey()` and `entry.getValue()` directly), but that's mostly a matter of style.

Comment: Again, you can retrieve the `Car` instance corresponding to a given name -- if there is one -- by passing the name to your `Map`'s `get()` method.  You can do whatever is appropriate with the return value (a reference to the requested object) -- store it in a variable, invoke methods on it, inspect any public fields it may have, *etc*..  Exactly what you *should* do with it is for you to determine, based on your requirements and the characteristics of your `Car` class.